# Link to pages on site without .html extension appearing in browser?

Tags: htaccess, redirects, url, mod-rewrite

I've modified my .htaccess file to allow access to html files without having to include the extension on the end, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/document
```

directs to

`www.mysite.com/document.html`

However, when I want to link to pages within my site using something like `<a href="page.html"></a>` I still get the .html appearing in the URL.

So am I allowed to exclude the extension and leave a link as `<a href="page"></a>` so that the extension doesn't appear in the browser? Or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, make your links match your URLs.

Comment: Surely this bad practice? If you create a link like `<a href="page"></a>` how does the browser know how to interpret it? For all it knows, it could be an image file.

Comment: The browser doesn't know that a .html page is a web page, some are .cgi, some are .php, some are .aspx.  The browser requests it, then the server sends the correct MIME type back.

Comment: @Anime163 Definitely **No.** Browser analyse server response headers (`Content-Type` in particular) as well as actual file content to identify correct format (display/processing method). It is not a surprise to see on the web file with .jpg extension that in fact is .png file (or other way around). If on my site all pages have `.do` extension -- how browser should treat them (accordingly to your logic)?

Comment: Thanks for the responses! So if I go through my whole site removing the extensions on the links to html files, that's an acceptable way to do it?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.